# cordova : running ionic cordova run android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hi I have the below error while I run the ionic command (`ionic cordova run android`). Any clue will be appreciated. My Java is 9.0.1 and the error message doesn't makes sense to me. Please suggest your thoughts.

> ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1
>   Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
>
> [17:09:02]  lint finished in 2.73 s
>
> D:\Personal\ionicapp>ionic -v
>   3.19.0
>
> D:\Personal\ionicapp>cordova platform ls
>   Installed platforms:
>     android 6.3.0
>   Available platforms:
>     blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
>     browser ~5.0.0
>     ios ~4.5.1
>     osx ~4.0.1
>     ubuntu ~4.3.4 (deprecated)
>     webos ~3.7.0
>     windows ~5.0.0
>     www ^3.12.0

Answer (score 0):

I had to download the JDK 1.8 from Oracle
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html